# Inserting array of nodes into Neo4j using Cypher's FOREACH getting slower as data is added

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using Cypher over the REST API to create unique nodes and relationships in relatively large groups.

My data model is simple: `(node1:Account {id:xx})-[:follows]->(node2:Account {id:yy})`
where `Account:id` is a unique parameter (not the Neo-generated one) and has a constraint.

I have a list of ids that I am adding that node1 follows, which I put in a map and feed as a parameter.

The Cypher query I'm using (mostly with help from here) is:

```
params = {nodes: [{"id": id}, {"id": id}..]}

MATCH (node1:Account {id: 12345)  
FOREACH (n in {nodes} | MERGE(node2:Account {id: n.id})  
MERGE (node1)-[r:FOLLOWS]->(node2))  
SET node1.lastFetch=timestamp()
```

This works. It uses an existing node for node2 or creates one if necessary and makes a the new relationship. But it is getting progressively slower the more nodes I have in the DB. I am adding about 500 at a time, which takes about 20 seconds. When I first started it was almost instant. The DB currently has about 16k Account nodes.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I'm pretty new with Neo4j, so I'm not sure what is considered good performance. Should I be expecting better performance (it's running on an old intel mac tower) or do these sort of mass inserts normally take a while.

Comment: What are your indices like? Do you have a unique constraint or at least an index for `:Account(id)`? Have you tried using the transactional endpoint?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write out your question properly, by the way. (+1)

Comment: @jjaderberg thanks. Yes, :Account(id) has a unique constraint. I'll be googling transactional endpoint now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I recently decided to change the naming convention of my labels to be a little more consistent. When I removed old labels and added new ones it didn't occur to me that I would need to reestablish the indexes and constraints. When I looked a the schema in the neo4j-shell I saw my constraints and indexes on my old labels. Basically I was working without an index on `:Account(id)` and `:ACCOUNT(id)` wasn't doing me much good any more.

I appreciate the prod to get me to take a second look at the indexes.